# Can't pass values to .net mvc Controller using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The idea is simple.

I want to wrap a Json data and using jQuery Ajax to pass the data to controller.

Here is the model definition.

```
public class SearchModel
{
        public int answerValue;
        public int year;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
 $(function() {
            var answerValue = $('#answerValue').val();
            var year = $('#year').val();
            var data = { "answerValue": answerValue, "year": year };

            //data = answerValue;
            $('#btn1').click(function () {

                $.post("home/AnswersSearch", data, function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                });
            });

        });
```

Code on the controller side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnswersSearch(SearchModel model)
{
    //do something
    return Content("1");
}
```

Comment: The ajax method is call a method named `AnswersSearch()` but all you have shown a method named `RespondentAnswersSearch()`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke THanks for the reply! I have changed that, still it doesn't work.

Comment: So what is the problem? What errors do you get? (and always use `'@Url.Action("AnswersSearch", "Home")'` to generate the correct url)

Comment: And I assume `SearchModelmodel model` is also a typo?

Comment: The problem is, the values of model are null(both answerValue and year). @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Because they are fields, not properties - add getters and setters - `public int answerValue { get; set; }`

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Thanks a lot!  @Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 0):

try sending back a SearchModel object like so:

```
var data = { "SearchModel": { "answerValue": answerValue, "year": year } };
```